# YouTube number of favourites

Tags: c#, youtube-api

I am working/playing :) with the YouTube API. I can get for each user their favourites videos, using GetFavoriteFeed(), but It is possible to get the inverse option? I mean get from a video how many times has been marked as a favourite?
In fact, when you click favourite on a video then if you see the statistics of the video (YouTube webpage), in favourites point there is always a 0 :S
Thx!!

Answer (score 1):

It's supposed to be returned in the `favoriteCount` attribute of `yt:statistics` for a given video, but yeah, I'm only getting back 0 for all the videos I look at as well.

It might be the the YouTube stopped making that information publicly available, and as a result it's no longer displayed on the webpage or via the API. If that's the case, I'll ask the technical writers to get the [documentation for the API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference#youtube_data_api_tag_yt%3astatistics) updated to reflect that.

Comment: Yes, like you said it is supposed...:S, I totally agree with you to ask technical writes to update YouTube API documentation :)

Comment: I confirmed that it's no longer exposed publicly, and the docs will be updated.