# FavoriteCount from YouTube API getting zero (0)

Tags: youtube-api, favorites

I am using YouTube API call as following to retrieve FavoriteCount  for Video : -

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=@VideoId&v=2&author=@authorname

@VideoId - passing VideoId and @authorname - passing the author name.

I am parsing the response from above API call for FavoriteCount from statistics node.

Before 2 Month ago, I am getting the  FavoriteCount  values properly. e.g - 1, 4 etc.

But, from last month I am observing that for all videos - getting FavoriteCount  values as Zero from above API call.  Anyone have any idea about this issue or  any solution to retrieve the correct FavoriteCount for YouTube videos ?

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12722177/youtube-number-of-favourites