# why is favoritecount zeroed, even for my own videos?

Tags: count, youtube-api, public, favorites

Related to

[YouTube number of favourites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12722177/youtube-number-of-favourites)
[FavoriteCount from YouTube API getting zero (0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13393690/favoritecount-from-youtube-api-getting-zero-0)

Even when I'm authed, I can't get favoriteCount for my own videos.  It shows as zero (even though I can see private details like keywords)

It seems broken.  Is there any way to get total favorite counts for my own videos?

Comment: As explained in  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12722177/youtube-number-of-favourites, this info will not be available going forward.

Comment: That post confirms that it's not available publicly.  I'm talking about for my own account.

Answer (score 1):

This data is no longer available for either public requests or requests authenticated as the owner of the video. Sorry to disappoint, but it's working as intended.